KMP & Compose Multiplatform - Error: 'kotlin.native.cacheKind' is explicitly set to 'none'
After forking some KMP projects, I keep getting this error when trying to building :
* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error: 'kotlin.native.cacheKind' is explicitly set to 'none'.
This option significantly slows the Kotlin/Native compiler.
Compose Multiplatform Gradle plugin manages this property automatically based on a Kotlin compiler version being used.
  * Recommended action: remove explicit 'kotlin.native.cacheKind=none' from gradle.properties. 
  * Alternative action: disable cache kind management by adding 'compose.kotlin.native.manageCacheKind=false' to your 'gradle.properties'.
    at org.jetbrains.compose.experimental.internal.ConfigureNativeCompilerCachingKt.checkExplicitCacheKind(configureNativeCompilerCaching.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.compose.experimental.internal.ConfigureNativeCompilerCachingKt.access$checkExplicitCacheKind(configureNativeCompilerCaching.kt:1)

And the solution proposed is not optimal :
compose.kotlin.native.manageCacheKind=false

But I'm wondering is there is any better solution than this ? (I don't like the idea to just deactivated Compose's ability to manage cache)
